# How to place a div at the bottom right of an overflow scroll

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to place some buttons at the bottom of a "scrolling view", I have seen lots of examples on this, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. So I'll try to explain:
[image]

As you can see from the picture above I want to place the "account icons", as in "Bane 1", but when the descriptive text becomes larger than the inner card, the icons seem to stay at 1% from the bottom. I want them to be at the bottom of the "scrollable view". Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks :)
(code below)

```css
.task
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00AA9E 
    &:last-child
        border-bottom: none

    

.container
    padding: 0
  

.reperationstyper
    float: left
    background-color: white
    height: 100%
    width: 3%

.smorring
    @extend .reperationstyper
    background-color: #90AB00


.kampagne
    @extend .reperationstyper
    background-color: #C14848

.reperation
    @extend .reperationstyper
    background-color: #D69966

.taskRow
    position: relative
    height: 100%
    margin-left: 0
    overflow: auto
    .button
        background: none !important
        border: none
        padding-right: 20% 
        float: right

.task-content
    
    padding-top: 1%
    p
        color: gray
.buttons
    padding-top: 2%
    padding-left: 0
    padding-right: 0

.empRow
    float: right
    margin-right: -30px
    margin-left: -30px
    position: absolute
    right: 50%
    bottom: 0.1%

.empButton
    float: right
    display: inline-block
    background: none
    border: none 
    bottom: 1%
```

```html
 <div class="container task" [ngStyle]="{'height': 'calc(100% /' + event.task.length + ')'}" *ngFor="let task of event.task; let i = index">
                <div class="smorring" *ngIf="event.task[i].TaskType == 0"></div>
                <div class="kampagne" *ngIf="event.task[i].TaskType == 1"></div>
                <div class="reperation" *ngIf="event.task[i].TaskType == 2"></div>
                
                <div class="row taskRow" style=" height: 100%; width: 97%">
                  <div class="col-10 task-content" >
                    <h6>{{task.heading}}</h6>
                    <p>{{task.description}}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-2 buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="button btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom"><md-icon class="task-info-button" [ngStyle]="{color: '#00AA9E', 'font-size': '180%'}">assignment</md-icon></button>
                    <div class="container empRow">
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let employee of task.requiredPersonnel; let i = index">
                        <button type="button" *ngIf="task.requiredPersonnel[i].type == 1" class="empButton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom"><md-icon class="task-info-button" [ngStyle]="{color: '#2CA800', 'font-size': '180%'}">assignment_ind</md-icon></button>       
                        <button type="button" *ngIf="task.requiredPersonnel[i].type == 0" class="empButton"><md-icon class="task-info-button" [ngStyle]="{color: '#CC0000', 'font-size': '180%'}">assignment_ind</md-icon></button>             
                      </ng-container>
                    </div>     
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

EDIT:
I've make a working plunker, but here the problem doesn't seem to occur, can someone spot the mistake? 
https://plnkr.co/edit/xfBpmV?p=preview

Comment: you have to post a working snippet

Comment: But the snippet tool, doesn't have angular 2..?

Comment: post it as html so people try to help you, but this way no one could try

Comment: I've added a plunker ;)

Comment: Check, if you have `position:relative` to `.card-body[_ngcontent-c0]` instead of `.row[_ngcontent-c0]` you will see the issue as shown in Bane2

Comment: Nice spotted @SuprajaGanji! But that's the weird thing, the `position:relative` is on the row in the snippet as well.

Comment: Is your issue solved ?

Comment: No, because `position:relative` it is currently on .row, and if I change to card-body nothing changes.

Comment: By the way, the nested "cards" are draggable (using dragular) maybe it's their styling which messes with the div 

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `min-height`

```
  .fixed-height {
    min-height: 170px;
  }
```

and give this class to

```
    <div class="col-md-10 fixed-height">
      <h6>Heading</h6>
      <p>nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
    </div>
```

find the updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rDcp6UCiS3zINIYDEdfD?p=preview)